# Create Observable from side-effects in Do block

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

With Reactive Extensions it is generally suggested to leave `Select` to be pure functions, i.e. without any side effects. Then when the side-effect is needed, either place it at the end of the pipeline with a `Subscribe`, or as a last resort in the middle of pipeline with a `Do`.

Ideally I would go for the last option (Do), but in my current situation, similar to the following block of code, I have a `Select` with side-effects, as I need to know the outcome from the operation in order to perform some logic later on. Examples of the outcome could be:

- whether the operation completed successfully or failed, in order to show errors to users;
- some number crunched by the operation, that is needed in a further observable pipeline.

Anyway, here's a code sample:

```
IObservable<Unit> inputStream = /* generate stream... */;

IObservable<OperationResult> operationOneStream = inputStream.Select(_ => 
{
  try 
  {
    /* side effect: do something, that can also throw... */

    return OperationResult.Success;  // use a simple Enum
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    /* compensate error: do something ... */

    return OperationResult.ErrorInOperationOne;
  }
});

// operationOneStream is used to build further streams down the chain, it's not "final".

IObservable<OperationResult> operationTwoStream = operationOneStream
  .Where(result => result == OperationResult.Success)
  // here in between some more operations: delay, select returning a stream, switch, ...
  .Select(_ => 
  {
    try 
    {
      /* side effect: do something, that can also throw... */

      return OperationResult.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      /* compensate error: do something ... */

      return OperationResult.ErrorInOperationTwo;
    }
  });

// then a third operation, running when nr. 2 is successful

/* ... */

/* Then, operationOne could be merged with other similar operations, 
 * so to grab their error streams and treat them in a single block.
*/
IObservable<SomeType> allOperationsStream = Observable.Merge(
  operationOneStream, operationTwoStream /*, ... */);

IDisposable subscription = allOperationsStream
  .Where(result => result != OperationResult.Success)
  .Subscribe(result => /* do something with error */);
```

Now I'd like to understand if there's a way to switch from `Do` to `Subscribe` in order to be even more explicit about those side-effects. In that case, the Subscribe *stops the chain* so, in order to grab output from the operation and use that later, I would resort to a Subject and feed that when operation completes or fails. But then again, Subjects are generally discouraged unless really needed.

Is there a more expressive code? Thanks all

**EDIT:** after various comments, I added more code so to show a more complete example. Also I fixed some errors in exposing the current situation, which I think were confusing.

Comment: `Do` doesn't return anything, so it won't have any real impact later in your pipeline (maybe a transposition error from `Select`?). Could you give an example of how you intend to use side-effects later in your pipeline? Your current example has you performing an operation and passing a result to the end of the stream which is exactly in-line with how you should be using Rx, without any visible side-effects.

Comment: I'd hoped not to dive into details of operation, let's see. The *input* streams in this scenario are generated out of regular NET events (out of my control at the moment). Some of those so-called *operations* have side-effects because if they are successful they cause further events to be raised, which give new observable values down the pipeline. On the other side, if the operation fails no further event will be raised, no new observable later, which is fine: but I grab the error to show it to user & log. Is that a little more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely follow what you're after, but possibly you're just trying to chain multiple observables together using a selectmany?

```
(from a in Observable.Return(1)
 from b in Observable.Return(2)
 select b
).Subscribe(x => {}, ex => {})
```

You could also build the error handling into this like so:

```
(from a in Observable.Return(1)
 from result in Observable.Return(2)
                          .Select(x => OperationResult.Success)
                          .Catch<OperationResult, Exception>(ex => { return Observable.Return(OperationResult.Error);})
  select result)
  .Subscribe(x => {}, ex => {});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on building the error handling: I'll check if I can apply that to current scenario. Trying to answer your question: I'm trying to understand if there's a better, more expressive way, if I want to: * perform some operation upon an observable occurrence, * keep its side effects, * feed operation success to a further observable, * feed operation failure to a further observable

Comment: About your error handling suggestion, 1 question: if you Catch the exception and turn it into a *regular* OperationResult value, there is no more exception, so why the OnError handler in Subscribe?

Comment: I would say it's always a good idea to handle any other errors in the stream which might occur.

Comment: So in this case you would handle errors both in OnNext, when OperationResult is not Success, as well as in OnError ?

Comment: It really depends on what you wanted to do when you detected that one of the observable streams has thrown an exception. If the 2nd observable can potentially error, but you still wanted to carry on processing items from the 1st observable, then Catch it as above, log the error, and return an empty Observable so that the inner observable completes. If on the other hand, you can't recover from any of the Observables throwing an exception, then you may as well let it flow through to the error handler in the Subscribe block. Once this has happened, no more OnNext()s should occur.

Comment: (there's probably no need to propagate the OperationResult, unless you have a specific need for it, i.e. summing up all the success/failures)